# C3.js chart title overlapped if I change the size of title

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

When I changed the size of line chart title, it's overlapped, and the x and y property can't work. But according to this [pull request](https://github.com/c3js/c3/pull/1025/commits/35f170a804b126e409bf934c947cae0a8ee3b1f8), it should work.

I found it was because it's in the SVG of the chart. And the size of SVG was controlled by the config but change the size of chart can't solve it.

```js
// Code goes here
(function(){
  
  var chart = c3.generate({ 
      title: {
        text: 'My Line Chart',
        y: 100
      },
      data: {
          columns: [
              ['data', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
          ]
      },
      legend: {
          position: 'inset'
      }, 
      grid: {
        y: {
            show: true
        }
      },
      axis: {
          y: {
              label: {
                  text: 'Y Axis Label',
                  position: 'outer-top'
              } 
          }
      }
  });
  
  d3.select('#chart .c3-title')
    .style('font-size', '4em')


})();
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#chart {
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a padding at the top...

```
padding: {
  top: 20
}
```

... and set the `dominant-baseline` of the text to `central`:

```
.style("dominant-baseline", "central")
```

Alternatively, just translate it down.

Here is the code with that change:

```js
// Code goes here
(function(){
  
  var chart = c3.generate({
      padding: {
      top: 20
    },
      title: {
        text: 'My Line Chart',
        y: 100
      },
      data: {
          columns: [
              ['data', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
          ]
      },
      legend: {
          position: 'inset'
      }, 
      grid: {
        y: {
            show: true
        }
      },
      axis: {
          y: {
              label: {
                  text: 'Y Axis Label',
                  position: 'outer-top'
              } 
          }
      }
  });
  
  d3.select('#chart .c3-title')
    .style('font-size', '4em')
    .style("dominant-baseline", "central")


})();
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#chart {
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, you have helped me solved two problems. I very appreciate it.